# can we identify which HDD has the operating system installed in the RAID configuration

Tags: partitioning, raid, raid-5

I have a server using windows 2008 R2 and using a RAID configuration as storage. can I find out which HDD has the operating system installed in the RAID configuration?

Comment: depends on the RAID mode? could be all of them ...

Comment: If Windows was installed on a RAID then all of the disks contain Windows.

Comment: The whole point of RAID is to **not** rely on a single disk for storing your data. In the case of RAID-1 (which you tagged your question with), a copy of your OS will be present on both disks. With other RAID types, your data may be spread around multple disks.

Comment: @StarCat - you should post this as an answer, methinks.

Comment: @StarCat I'm using RAID 5 on the server, can it still be known which HDD has the operating system installed? anyway thanks for your help

Comment: No you can't, RAID-5 works in a very different way. Your data is combined with parity for redundancy and striped over all the disks in the set in such a way that you can lose a disk in the set and will still be able to rebuild the data. This is called N+1 redundancy. All disks store parts of the data and there is no single disk that has the entire OS installed. Why did you mark your question "RAID-1"?

Comment: A more detailed description: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_5

Comment: @StarCat is my mistake, thanks for your help bro i got the point

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your answer

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for your answer bro

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, RAID-5 works in a very different way. Your data is combined with parity for redundancy and striped over all the disks in the set in such a way that you can lose a disk in the set and will still be able to rebuild the data. This is called N+1 redundancy. All disks store parts of the data and there is no single disk that has the entire OS installed.

- @StarCat